# Remove a defined name or broken reference in excel using C#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, excel-addins

My aim is to delete all the `"#REF"` from within an excel file in the workbook.xml. What I can currently do is find all the "#REF" references throughout my workbook however I'm not sure how to delete them from within the file.

My code is as fallows

This piece of code finds all the `"#REF"` in the file

```
        var spreadsheet = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\Craig\Desktop\newTest.xlsx", false);
        var workbook = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart;
        var names = workbook.Workbook.DefinedNames;





        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"#REF");

        int count= result.InactiveNamedRangeCount = names.Count(n => regex.IsMatch(n.InnerText));
        Console.WriteLine(count);
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            if (regex.IsMatch(name.InnerText))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name.InnerText);
            }
        }
```

And here I'm trying to go though each `#REF` to delete it using a foreach but it doesn't delete any of them and I'm not sure why.

```
foreach (var name in names)
        {
            if (regex.IsMatch(name.InnerText))
            {
                name.Remove();
                Console.WriteLine(name.InnerText);
                Console.WriteLine(count);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you actually save the `SpreadsheetDocument` after you removed them?

Comment: @CharlesMager I'm using the OpenXml reference have you got any idea how I would save it using this?

Comment: The [`Save`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.workbook.save(v=office.14).aspx) method on `Workbook` would be my guess. You'll also have to change how you're opening it as you've passed `false` for `isEditable`.

Comment: @CharlesMager My `workbook` does not contain a definition for `save`

Comment: No, it doesn't - that's `WorkbookPart`. `Workbook` does, though (see [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.workbook.save(v=office.14).aspx) I referred to). So `workbook.Workbook.Save()`.

Comment: I added this to my code `var work = workbook.Workbook;` and then `work.Save();` and it's still not deleting the #REF. I also have passed true to my spreadsheet

Comment: Alright it is working now however it's only deleting on #REF every time I run the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.spreadsheetdocument.aspx) and also at [this How To](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc861607.aspx), as most of it applies here.

First, when you open the `SpreadsheetDocument`, the second parameter should be `true`:

> The second parameter is either true or false and represents whether you want the file to be opened for editing. Any changes that you make to **the document will not be saved if this parameter is false**.

Second, you need to call [`Save`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.workbook.save(v=office.14).aspx) on `Workbook` after you remove the names.

Third, `SpreadsheetDocument` implements `IDisposable`. You should wrap it with a `using` statement to ensure it is disposed when you've finished with it. This will ensure the changes are flushed and the file stream closed. From [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.spreadsheetdocument.dispose(v=office.15).aspx), dispose:

> Flushes and saves the content, closes the document, and releases all resources.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: What exactly should my using statement contain?

Comment: @CraigGallagher All of your code that works on the document. Like [the example in the How To](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc861607.aspx#sectionSection3) (there's a small typo, `using` is lowercase).

Comment: I've done that but for some reason it only deletes on Ref at a time even though I have it in a foreach

Comment: @CraigGallagher try changing `foreach (var name in names)` to `foreach (var name in names.ToList())`. I think the structure is a linked list, so removing the first name means the enumeration will stop (as there is no longer a next node). Caching with `ToList` will work around that.

Comment: I've debugged this and after Regex finds the match once in the if statement the next time it enters into the foreach it skips the if statement as if it can't find another match.

Comment: Yes changing it to `names.ToList`  did work. Thanks a million